# PHP While loop not finishing after nested foreach finishes

Tags: php, loops

The outer while loop never resumes after the inner foreach loop finishes.  When the inner finishes the file reports back to the command as if it has completed.  It never echos "+++++++".

The script is meant to pull some data from an api and save that data to a table, the api returns records in batches of 1000 so the outer while loop pulls multiple sets of 1000. The script returns 'Saved' alot of times but never the '++++++'.  Any ideas?

```
while ($iterations > 0) {

        $results = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://foo.bar?start=$start$limit=1000"), true);

        foreach ($results['SearchResult']['Records'] as $result) {

                //search table
                $query = "SELECT id from sometable where name = '".$result['something']."'";
                $res = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                $branch = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) or die(mysql_error());

                //save to table
                $query = "INSERT INTO `table` some values)";
                if (mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error())) {
                    echo 'SAVED';
                }   


        }
        $start = $start+1000;
        $iterations--;

        echo "++++++++++++++++++++";
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define $iterations?

Comment: Stop using the mysql extension. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_` functions for they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: Is it possible one of your die() calls is being invoked? have you tried omitting them to see the output, or are there any errors in the log?

Comment: Still trying to understand the big picture. You say "Saved" get's returned a lot of times. What about your tables though? Are they actually getting updated? Do you see any information or just the word "Saved"?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file_get_contents("http://foo.bar?start=$start&limit=1000")` with an ampersand sign instead of a dollar sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be causing problems:

```
if (mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error())) {
```

The `die()` command is processed as part of your `if` statement.

Instead, I'd do something like this:

```
$q=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
if ($q) {
```

Comment: showdev:  I thought since it would run through that if time and time again saving that it wouldn't catch when it was finished with the foreach.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Everyone else: I used the old mysql I know, I shouldn't. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't really need the die() unless you want to script to exit when a query error is encountered. Just checking the [return value of `mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues) will be enough to catch problematic queries. TRUE means it was successful, FALSE means it failed. `if (mysql_query($query, $conn)) {...}`